# rollapply how to "ignore" certain observations and use variable width

Tags: r, rollapply

I am trying to calculate mean for some data along a non-regular date sequence. For example, I have minute level data for specific periods of time during the day and I am interested in calculating 5 minute averages. However, I am not sure how does the `width` parameter in rollapply works when is specified as a list.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

length = 16

set.seed(10)

dxf <- data.frame(
  date = seq(Sys.time(), by = "59 sec", length.out = length),
  value = runif(length)
)

# Create a "discontinuity"
dxf$date[8:length] <- dxf$date[8:length] + 3600*24

# Add some noise
dxf$date <- dxf$date + runif(length, 0, 1)

diff(dxf$date)

dxf %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(
    diff = c(as.numeric(diff(date)), NA),
    mean = rollapply(value, width = 5, mean, partial = TRUE, align = "left")
  )

# This is what I need. Therefore, I need a variable width but adjusting to the discontinuity in the rows.
mean1 <- mean(dxf$value[1:5])
mean2 <- mean(dxf$value[2:6])
mean3 <- mean(dxf$value[3:7])
mean4 <- NA # Only have 4 values mean(dxf$value[4:7])
mean5 <- NA # Only have 3 values mean(dxf$value[5:7])
mean6 <- NA # Only have 2 values mean(dxf$value[6:7])
mean7 <- NA # Only have 1 values mean(dxf$value[7:7])
mean8 <- mean(dxf$value[7:11])
etc.
```

Comment: Maybe remove or replace bad data with `NA` before `rollapply`?

Comment: The value  in row 14 is used to calculate the mean for rows 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14.  so if `value[14]` is set to NA `mean[10:14]` will be NA

Comment: @TonyLadson; Correct. I changed the reprex a little bit to make it shorter but I will need NAs in this case for row 4:7.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a tricky problem.  Here is one approach

1 Generate a 1 min sequence from the first to the last datetime

2 Interpolate so we have a value at each 1 min. This includes interpolating across the discontinuity

3 Calculate the running 5 min mean based on the 1 min interpolated values

4 Remove the values where the gap in the original datetime values is too large

Also, take care with time zones, best to set these to some deliberately chosen value or UTC which the lubridate functions do by default.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RcppRoll)
library(lubridate)



dxf <- tibble(
  date = seq(from = ymd_hms('2019-08-14 09:06:05'), by = "59 sec", length.out = 30),
  value = runif(30)
)

dxf$date[15:30] <- dxf$date[15:30] + 3600*24 # discontinuing
dxf$date <- dxf$date + round(runif(30)) # noise

dxf <- dxf %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd_hms(date),
         date_num = as.numeric(date),
         diff = date_num - lag(date_num))


discontinuity <- which(dxf$diff > 70)



n = nrow(dxf)

date_seq <- seq(from = dxf$date_num[1], to = dxf$date_num[n], by = 60) # create a 1 min sequence

value_interp = approx(x = dxf$date_num, y = dxf$value, xout = date_seq)  # interpolate values for the 5 min sequence

df <- tibble(
  date = as_datetime(date_seq),
  mean_value = RcppRoll::roll_mean(value_interp$y, n = 5, fill = NA, align = 'left'))

df %>% 
  filter(date < dxf$date[discontinuity - 1] | date > dxf$date[discontinuity])
```

Comment: At this time I am avoiding to interpolate the data but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We could extract the date, group them and then use `rollmean`

```
library(dplyr)

dxf %>%
  mutate(d1 = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(d1) %>%
  mutate(mean = zoo::rollmean(value, 5, align = "left", fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-d1)


#   date                 value   mean
#   <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2019-08-14 12:49:09 0.507   0.404
# 2 2019-08-14 12:50:08 0.307   0.347
# 3 2019-08-14 12:51:07 0.427   0.341
# 4 2019-08-14 12:52:07 0.693     NA    
# 5 2019-08-14 12:53:06 0.0851    NA    
# 6 2019-08-14 12:54:05 0.225     NA    
# 7 2019-08-14 12:55:04 0.275     NA    
# 8 2019-08-15 12:56:02 0.272   0.507
# 9 2019-08-15 12:57:01 0.616   0.476
#10 2019-08-15 12:58:01 0.430   0.472
#11 2019-08-15 12:59:00 0.652   0.457
#12 2019-08-15 12:59:58 0.568   0.413
#13 2019-08-15 13:00:58 0.114     NA    
#14 2019-08-15 13:01:56 0.596     NA    
#15 2019-08-15 13:02:56 0.358     NA    
#16 2019-08-15 13:03:54 0.429     NA
```

**data**

```
set.seed(10)

dxf <- data.frame(
   date = seq(Sys.time(), by = "59 sec", length.out = length),
   value = runif(length)
)
dxf$date[8:length] <- dxf$date[8:length] + 3600*24
dxf$date <- dxf$date + runif(length, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `w[i]` is number of elements of `date` that are less than or equal to `date[i] + 300` minus `i - 1` noting that 300 refers to 300 seconds.

```
date <- dxf$date
w <- findInterval(date + 300, date) - seq_along(date) + 1

rollapply(dxf$value, w, mean, align = "left") * ifelse(w < 5, NA, 1)

# same
sapply(seq_along(w), function(i) mean(dxf$value[seq(i, length = w[i])])) * 
  ifelse(w < 5, NA, 1)
```